# Some element's missing from any Java IDE Intellisense

Tags: java, intellisense

I've installed Eclipse and i've tried to import the java.awt.BorderLayout package through the autocompletation (through ctrl+space). Not only Eclipse didn't found the suggestion when i've tried through the line "new BorderLayout()", but it didn't also work through "import java.awt. ". The crazy thing is that if i manually write "import java.awt.BorderLayout;", it get recognized.
I've tried switching IDE (Visual Studio Code), but it gives the same problem. How can I fix this situation, since this is happening with other packages as well?
In eclipse i've used the JDK 16 included with it, and with Visual Studio Code i've manually installed the JDK through the terminal.
The OS is Pop_OS 20.04 (Based on Ubuntu).

Comment: Definitely. I don't know how did I miss that, thank you so much!